# How to make these 2 jquery plugin work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, lightbox

i was making a image slider with a lightbox, but since i cant find any easy plugin with both function, i have to mix it with 2 jquery plugin, but its never works. 
Can i using both jquery plugin at the same page??

Here is my html code :

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".slider").colorbox({rel:'slider', slideshow:true});

            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true,
            continuous: true 
        });
    }); 

</script>

<div id="container">

<div id="header"></div>

<div id="content">

<div id="slider">
        <ul>                
            <li><a class="slider" href="images/01.jpg"><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="slider" href="images/02.jpg"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a  class="slider"href="images/03.jpg"><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="slider" href="images/04.jpg"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a  class="slider"href="images/05.jpg"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>          
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working is not because you have included two jquery plugins.
But because you have included jquery file twice .Remove one and it will work

Here you should include

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and remove this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```